# What is the best way to connect ibm cloud app-connect with mq?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mq, ibm-app-connect

In view
https://cloud.ibm.com/resources
I m having two elements

- Cloud Foundry services -> App Connect
- Services -> MQ

Within App Connect I would like to use MQ.
How do I tell cloud.ibm.com that the two shall work with each other?

In appconnect.ibm.com/create I would like to work with that MQ - but don't know how.

In appconnect.ibm.com/catalog/apps -> MQ I also do not see a smart way to connect to MQ.

Comment: When you create the MQ instance it should provide details on how it can be accessed in MQ client mode.  Would you not just use this information to setup ACE to connect to MQ in client mode?  Sorry I don't have any first hand experience with the cloud version of either, but this would work if you ran ACE and MQ on separate "on prem" servers.  I know IBM has people monitoring the 'ibm-mq' tag so someone from IBM may be able to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Can you please provide an overview of what you are trying to do. It reads like you want to configure App Connect to use MQ as its underlying message delivery mechanism. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I just deployed IBM MQ and IBM App Connect to test this. In this example, I connect to MQ from App Connect and deploy a flow that is triggered when a message arrives on `DEV.QUEUE.1`. The flow then puts a new message, copying the payload from the first, on to `DEV.QUEUE.2`. It looks like you already have IBM App Connect and IBM MQ services deployed, so I will dive straight into the configuration of MQ and the App Connect flow. Here's the steps I took:

1. On the MQ cloud deployment I followed the guided tutorial, created a Queue Manager `QM1` and then created, and downloaded an `API key`. I made a note of the username shown on the Application Credentials page.
2. I also made a note of the `Connection Information` shown for my Queue Manager on the Queue Managers page. This information can also be downloaded by clicking the `Connection Information` button at the top right corner of the page.
3. In the IBM App Connect `Catalog` view, I added IBM MQ as an application and created a new account `Account 1`. [image: IBM App Connect Catalog view]
4. I then populated the account configuration with the Queue Manager details collected in Step 2. [image: IBM MQ Account Configuration]
5. In the App Connect Dashboard view, I created a new `Event-driven flow`, Selected `MQ` from the applications list, `Account 1` and `New message on a queue`
6. I entered the inbound queue name `DEV.QUEUE.1`
7. I completed the flow by again selecting MQ from the `Applications` list, then `Put message to a queue` and this time I entered the queue name `DEV.QUEUE.2`. [image: IBM App Connect Flow]
8. I then started the flow using the menu in the top right corner.
9. To open the IBM MQ Console for testing, I selected `Administer` for my Queue Manager in the resource list view. [image: Administer IBM MQ Queue Manager]
10. Finally, I logged into the IBM MQ Console, selected `Manage`, clicked on `DEV.QUEUE.1` and then `Create` to put a simple test message. Returning back to the `Manage` view, I could see my message had been processed by IBM App Connect and was now on `DEV.QUEUE.2`. [image: IBM MQ Console Manage View]

Comment: Great write up on the specifics. Of this setup.

Comment: Thanks a million richc. 
So it was a long story to connect two things that are already known in the cloud.
In Step2 you had to copy Connection details to somewhere else.
In Step4, you entered them manually 
Maybe we generate some inspiration to IBM to offer a smarter solution for this task.

Comment: np [@matjung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151204/matjung) really pleased you are up and running. Thanks for the feedback which I will forward on.

Comment: [@matjung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151204/matjung) I have spoken to the dev team and they have taken onboard your feedback re. having to type data in multiple places. Assuming I have answered your question fully, would you be happy to mark the question as answered?

Comment: I did not check if your instructions are correct / incorrect. Maybe there is a better way available to connect them - that we don't know yet.

Comment: @matjung I would be happy to review the answer. Please could you expand on what you would like to see improved or refined.

Comment: Hi @richc maybe it could be done in less than 10 steps.
Maybe something with kubectl *.yaml